# SpriteKit prevent sprite from leaving screen without bouncing

Tags: ios, sprite-kit

I am using the accelerometer to move a sprite around the screen, and I am using spriteKit collisions to keep the sprite in the bounds of the screen. Is there a way I can prevent the sprite from bouncing off the sides of the screen? (the sprite should just stop on the edge of the screen)

Comment: Is there a way you can post some code?

Comment: Have you set the screen bounds in your class? So the player can't leave the screen?

Comment: You can set the restitution property of your nodes to 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting the restitution properties on the nodes to zero prevent bouncing. Thanks!

Answer (score 10):

Try `SKConstraint` The code would look something like this, and would constrain `sprite` to the scene. This code goes in your `scene` file:

```
let xRange = SKRange(lowerLimit:0,upperLimit:size.width)
let yRange = SKRange(lowerLimit:0,upperLimit:size.height)
//sprite.constraints = [SKConstraint.positionX(xRange,Y:yRange)] // iOS 9
sprite.constraints = [SKConstraint.positionX(xRange,y:yRange)]  // iOS 10
```

Comment: This is such a great answer - I had a huge block of code to check the bounds and velocity and see if it put the image past something. I reduced it all to just the lines of code above. Thanks so much Tonethar!

Comment: No prob!  "One of my most productive days was throwing away 1000 lines of code" - Ken Thompson - http://www.brainyquote.com/quotes/quotes/k/kenthompso254858.html